# Query Performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have a SQL Server table with over 11 million records. These records are organized by "Category" and "Platform". I am stumped by the following scenario ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE Category = 'session' AND Platform = 'windows';
-- Returns 1261500

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE Category = 'session' AND Platform = 'linux';
-- Returns 1890599
```

So there are over 600K more records associated with 'linux' than 'windows'.

However, this query returns in 6-9 seconds ...

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName WHERE Category = 'session' AND Platform = 'linux';
```

Yet this one I have to kill after waiting over 13 minutes for a result ...

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName WHERE Category = 'session' AND Platform = 'windows';
```

Oh ... I also have the following index on the table ...

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableName_CategoryPlatform] ON [dbo].[TableName]
(
    [Platform] ASC,
    [Category] ASC,
    [CreateDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Whiskey, Tango, Foxtrot?

Why does the search term make a difference, particularly since there is an index in place?

### **UPDATE**

I have just made the following observation ...

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName WHERE Platform = 'windows';
```

By dropping the *Category* from the query, the response is returned very quickly ...

### UPDATE 2

I have created a couple of execution plans as requested. The thing I noticed, however is that the percentages in the plans generated by the "Paste The Plan" utility and what I am getting in SSMS appear to be different so I am including, below each link, the percentages that I am seeing in Management Studio.

For the following Query (which works) ...

```
SELECT MAX([MessageID]) [MaxID] FROM [BoothComm].[UniversalMessageQueue] WHERE [MessagePlatform]='windows';
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk9q59CqZ

- 0% : Select
- 0% : Stream Aggregate
- 0% : Top
- 100% : Index Scan

The next query (which doesn't work) I can only provide an ESTIMATED execution plan.

```
SELECT 
   MAX(MessageID) AS [MaxID]
FROM BoothComm.UniversalMessageQueue
WHERE 
 MessageCategory = 'session'
 AND
 MessagePlatform = 'windows'
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1zqnq09-

- 0% : Select
- 0% : Stream Aggregate
- 0% : Top
- 0% : Nested Loops (Inner Join) -- Why is this there??
- 21% : Index Scan
- 79% : Key Lookup -- Also new and seems to want to take up more time than anything else

(thanks for all the help!)

### **UPDATE 3**

So after all of the below conversation and changes made I am still left with the question ...

Why does this query return in under 1 second (thanks to adding the ID to the index) ...

```
SELECT 
      MAX(MessageID) AS [MaxID]
FROM BoothComm.UniversalMessageQueue
WHERE 
    MessagePlatform = 'linux'
    AND
    MessageCategory = 'accounting'
```

And this one take 13 -22 seconds to run ...

```
SELECT 
      MAX(MessageID) AS [MaxID]
FROM BoothComm.UniversalMessageQueue
WHERE 
    MessagePlatform = 'windows'
    AND
    MessageCategory = 'accounting'
```

Same table, same indexes, execution plans are the absolute same. Everything is identical except for the **MessagePlatform** value. And the value which is responsible for the latency appears on fewer records than the other.

Comment: is `id` your clustering key?

Comment: What does the execution plan show and does it use your index?

Comment: How about if you add `ID` as an `INCLUDE` to the index?

Comment: @SqlZim No .. id is not the PK (there is a PK it's just not "id").

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I actually don't understand execution plans that much. Referencing the UPDATE observation, when I run the "estimated execution plan" against both queries, they ARE different but not sure what that means or how to post those results here.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Also, share your table schema.

Comment: Your query appears to be not using index at all or index is too fragmented.

Comment: Try using columns in order of specification in the index. 

    SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName WHERE Platform = 'windows' AND Category = 'session';

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom Are the statistics up to date? Try running `exec sp_updatestats`. Also you should try my prev tip about the covering index.

Comment: I have added ID to the index and re-ordered the select columns to match the index and the results are positive. Results were returned in 13 seconds. The second execution plan is still being used but it seems to be faster.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom note that ID should not be an indexed column but rather an include. 
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableName_CategoryPlatform] ON [dbo].[TableName]
(
    [Platform] ASC,
    [Category] ASC
) INCLUDE ([ID])`

Comment: @Magnus yes ... precisely what I did. But since it's included in the index why bother go back to the table to do the "Key Lookup"?

Comment: It shouldn't do a key lookup if you have it as an include. Did you try the `sp_updatestats`. Also for testing purposes try removing `CreateDate` from the index and see if that does any difference.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have permissions to run the `sp_updatestats` procedure and I cannot remove the _CreateDate_ as it will create issues for other processes which this index was actually created to resolve. I may try to create an additional index though, if we have the disc space ...

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom Looking at the execution plan for your "update 2" query - it uses two indexes. One is the Clustered one (likely your PK) and the other (MessagePlatform) which seems to use columns MessageQueueId, MessageId and MessagePlatform and is being scanned. It could look like MessagePlatform is the third column in the index instead of the first and based on your query, MessageId likely only needs to be an included column and not an indexed column to avoid it spilling into the other index

Answer (score 4):

Your queries are slow because the table is not normalized.  You should not be storing Category and Platforms as strings on every record.  Instead they should be in lookup tables with an integer primary key.  These keys would then be stored in your main table with appropriate non clustered indexes on each one.  Then you should add a clustered index to your main table on a column that makes sense to have sorted in ascending order (preferably a unique integer).

As to the actual problem you are encountering, if you have no clustered index defined, the data is stored in a heap (i.e. an unsorted pile of data).  The index you have will help but performance is hampered by the fact that you are using strings as keys, and from the looks of it these strings are not highly specific (many repeats).  SQL Server may simply be deciding to do a full scan to answer your question, as it is estimating that will be faster than any other method.

Comment: While I acknowledge and agree with the normalization practices you are describing, this table contains "snapshots" in time. The problem is that referenced values can be changed but these records cannot. So while 5 may be more efficient than 'windows', 5 may not always refer to 'windows' but this record must always reflect 'windows'.

Comment: Also, I DO have a clustered index defined (the primary key). It is just not involved in this query. Given that only one clustered index is allowed on a table, unclustered indexes are the only remaining option.

Comment: You could handle the history of the changes in the lookup table.  Create new lookups to add new values to the system.  Make sure to add datestamps as well to reflect when the changes took place.  As for the clustered index, they are used in every query behind the scenes.  Each non-clustered index stores the clustering key in order to point back to the original record.  It would help if you showed the table definition.